# Howto configure postfix to correctly handle greylisting when forwarding mail

Tags: postfix, greylisting

I have a postfix setup in which I use `virtual_alias_maps` to forward / alias mails to other addresses. In a specific sample scenario, my server would serve as an MX for the domain `mydomain.com` and I configured the following virtual alias:

```
peter@mydomain.com --> peter@otherdomain.com
```

where `otherdomain.com` is served from a third party server which implements grey listing.

In this scenario, when forwarding a mail for the first time to the `otherdomain.com` server, this would reject with a temporary error due to greylisting.

Is it possible to propagate this temporary error to the mail server I received the message from originally? 
I figure that my server currently would accept the message and append it to its own queue, practically making the greylisting on the target server useless.

Comment: The "correct" way to handle this would be to implement greylisting yourself, IMHO.

Comment: Nice that you reported this. It nicely explained what I was seeing here. 

Forwarding is a one way communication. The solution is not to forward.